# printing a list without it recognizing a line break. I dont know how to put this into words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I basically want my code to print something and the list is in between the paragraph repeatedly

```
sentence = '''lol hi
how are you'''

memes = list(sentence)
with open('lol.txt', 'w') as f:
    for part in memes:
        f.write(f"dang"\{part}"\n")
```

I want it to come out as:

```
dang l
dang o
dang l
dang h
dang i
dang h
dang o
```

but it comes out as:

```
dang l
dang o
dang l
dang h
dang i
dang 
dang h
```

Comment: You get a syntax error if you try to do this: `f.write(f"dang"\{part}"\n")`

Comment: What happened to the space after `lol` in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly check for `\n` (or a whitespace) (note I also fixed your f-strings):

```
with open('lol.txt', 'w') as f:
    for part in memes:
        if part in (' ', '\n'):
            continue
        f.write(f'dang {part}\n')
```